# How to get last value from a json in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have problem with a json, this json keeps updating, so the last entry will never be the same. This is the json:

```
{"channel":{"id":274304,"name":"Water","description":"Record water consumption.","latitude":"0.0","longitude":"0.0","field1":"Water","created_at":"2017-05-17T16:27:46Z","updated_at":"2017-05-19T01:01:07Z","last_entry_id":28},"feeds":[{"created_at":"2017-05-19T00:51:35Z","entry_id":1,"field1":"288"},{"created_at":"2017-05-19T00:51:50Z","entry_id":2,"field1":"304"}]}
```

I have something like this in my php code, where the variable $cool contains the decoded json.

```
$x= $cool->feeds[2]->field1;
```

But when the json updates, feeds[2] will not be the last entry. So i was thinking of using arrays to store all data. But i don't know how to do this. Can you help me?

Comment: use end($array) to find the last element. I suggest yoo to decode that JSON into array instead of object. I think it's easier for me.

Answer (score 4):

If `$cool->feeds` is an array as I assume, you can use [`end`](http://php.net/end) to get its last item:

```
$x = end($cool->feeds)->field1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the last element, you also can use array_pop()

```
$x = array_pop($cool->feeds)->field1;
```

Comment: \* Note: This modifies the array.